# Indexeddb sorting with multiple indexes

Tags: mysql, sorting, filtering, indexeddb, querying

I have a file object store by indexing `name and library_id` like below,

```
let objectStore = db.createObjectStore('file', { keyPath: 'id' });
    tempStore.createIndex('nameLibId', ['attributes.name', 'attributes.library_id'], { unique: false });
```

The object store contains multiple library id's files. I'd like apply the name sort to the particular library id's files. I tried indexing in the below format but it returns empty data.

```
    let self = this, 
        db = get(self, 'db'),
        transaction = db.transaction(["file"], "readonly"),
        objectStore = transaction.objectStore("file"),
        index = objectStore.index('nameLibId'),
        keyRange = IDBKeyRange.only('library_id')),
        req = index.getAll(keyRange);
        req.onsuccess = ((e)=>{
          console.log(e.target.result); // returns empty array
        });
```

Attached the screenshot of db model for reference.

[image]

1. `24536475`, `abc`, `created`, `jhgf` and `lastmodified` file names are belongs to a library id called `123`.
2. `Screen Shot..*` file names are belongs to an another library id called `234`.

I need the files which are sorted by name only the given library id. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

If your index is based on a properties array and you want to match something using `IDBKeyRange.only`, then your parameter to `IDBKeyRange.only` should also be an array. Right now you are comparing a basic string value against a properties array value, where of course nothing matches. In other words, you cannot query against a two-part array using only one part of it.

Furthermore, the parameter to IDBKeyRange.only isn't a property name, it is a value. You want to specify a value to match in the index's set of keypath values. For example, if your index was based exclusively on attributes.name, then you would want to specify a particular value within that index, such as "abc".

And so, taking into account the above two points, and given that your index is not a single value but is instead an array of two properties, you need to revise your parameter to IDBKeyRange.only to look for an array. Something like `IDBKeyRange.only(['abc', 'yoktc....']);`.

Now, this is further complicated by the fact that what you are doing in your code does not actually accomplish what you want. Ignoring the sort concern for a moment, you only want to use the id condition, and not the name, when matching rows of this index. So you might be tempted to try `IDBKeyRange.only([undefined, 'asdf'])`. Unfortunately this will not work at all because you cannot specify undefined (you will get a javascript error).

So, you must always query by both values, even though you only want to apply criteria to one of the values. The trick here is that you switch to using a different method than only. You use `IDBKeyRange.bound()`, and furthermore, you do a trick where you specify a criteria such as "smallest possible number is less than my number and my number is less than largest possible number", e.g. a condition that always is true. You use "smallest possible value" as your lower boundary, and "largest possible value" as your upper boundary.

Here is an example in your case. The smallest possible value of name I think is empty string. The largest possible value of name is probably any non-alphanumeric character, so let's use tilde "~". So, now we would rewrite the range parameter. Instead of using IDBKeyRange.only, we use IDBKeyRange.bound. It looks like the following (roughly):

```
var libId = ???;
var smallestNameValue = '';
var largestNameValue = '~';
var lowerBound = [smallestNameValue, libId];
var upperBOund = [largestNameValue, libId];
var range = IDBKeyRange.bound(lowerBound, upperBound);
```

Now, the second part, regarding sorting, and a major caveat of using indices that have multiple parts (not to be confused with the multiPart index property, ugh). And I myself get this backwards all the time, so I might even be wrong here and the above will work. The problem with the above is that one the first criterion is met the second is ignored, because of how the short-circuited array sorting algorithm works in indexedDB's comparison function. Your query is going to match everything, because every index row meets the criteria. So the trick to this is to always query first by the important condition, to basically pay attention to the order in which you specify your conditions. So what that means is that you need to switch the order of the properties you specified when creating the index, so that you can query first by libId and then by name.

Instead of `createIndex('nameLibId',['attributes.name','attributes.library_id']);` you want to do `createIndex('nameLibId',['attributes.library_id', 'attributes.name']);`. And this also means you need to swap your lower and upper bound queries, e.g. `var lowerBound = [libId, smallestNameValue];` (and don't forget to switch the upper).

As I mentioned in my answer on using compound indices, you can always using `indexedDB.cmp` to experiment. Right now, open up the console on this web page. In the console, type something like this:

```
indexedDB.cmp(['', '5'], ['~', '5']);
```

Take a look at the results.

Some final notes:

- Tilde might be the wrong thing to use, sorry but I am not bothering to remember, you could also just try any valid sentinel value, where by sentinel I mean any value you know will always come after all your other valid values
- As I point out in my other answer, if either prop is missing in the data the actual object won't match
- for cmp, -1 means left is less than right, 0 means left equals right, and 1 means left greater than right

Comment: I've tried as you said, but still I didn't get the exact results as expected, Could you please look into the twiddle and lemme know where did I do the mess. [https://ember-twiddle.com/056e2e753bc67734919c6d63784a1638?openFiles=routes.application.js%2C]?

Comment: I couldn't get the files which only has the library_id of `a123`.

Comment: @Jeevi I've modified your twiddle do try this and lemme know if it works. [https://ember-twiddle.com/056e2e753bc67734919c6d63784a1638?openFiles=routes.application.js%2C]

Comment: @Jeevi instead of "~" use something like "zzz", or use a variable type that indexedDB states is ordered after the string type regardless of value.

Comment: Number keys are less than date keys. Date keys are less than string keys. String keys are less than binary keys. Binary keys are less than array keys. Therefore you can use lowerbound like '[0, id]` because number less than any string, and upper bound like [[], id] because array greater than any string. I think. Test using indexedDB.cmp

Comment: Ok, one more attempt at being clear. Change the code to set smallestStringValue to the number 0, and set largestString value to an empty array.

Comment: A clear, helpful answer. Thanks Josh. I didn't know about indexedDB.cmp, another plus! I had been using [ Infinity ] as my upper bound and couldn't understand why it didn't work. I should have used [ []].